# Is it possible to cast service result automatically in the same type in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, casting, converters

**The facts:**

- I use a service reference to a WCF service
- The result of WCF service is structurally and logically the same as my type.

The type in my project:

```
namespace project.Data
{
    using System;

    public class TestPerson
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result type from WCF Service:

```
namespace externalServices.Data
{
    using System;

    public class TestPerson
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The Question:**

- It is possible to convert one type automatically to an other type?

At moment my solution looks like this:

```
// service call 
var serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
externalServices.Data.TestPerson externalTestPerson = serviceClient.GetTestPerson();
project.Data.TestPerson myTestPerson = new TestPerson
{
    Birthday = externalTestPerson.Birthday,
    Firstname = externalTestPerson.Firstname,
    Lastname = externalTestPerson.Lastname
};
```

I hope for a more ellegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to cast even if all fields and class names are completely equal by name and type.

Beside, you can use tool like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.codeplex.com/) to make the copy easy.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<externalServices.Data.TestPerson, project.Data.TestPerson>();
Mapper.Map<externalServices.Data.TestPerson>(testPerson); // Copy all fields that have the same name and the same type
```

Comment: Nice idea! But with a service reference it doesn't work for me.